# SQL Server: Avg, Max and Min in same query

Tags: sql-server

I have this setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Stores
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Agents
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [StoreID] [int] NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Sales
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AgentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [money] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Stores(Name) VALUES ('Paris');
INSERT INTO Stores(Name) VALUES ('New York');
INSERT INTO Stores(Name) VALUES ('Tokyo');
INSERT INTO Stores(Name) VALUES ('Rio de Janeiro');

INSERT INTO Agents (Name,StoreID) VALUES ('Michel', 1);
INSERT INTO Agents (Name,StoreID) VALUES ('Didier', 1);
INSERT INTO Agents (Name,StoreID) VALUES ('Gaston', 1);
INSERT INTO Agents (Name,StoreID) VALUES ('Mark', 2);
INSERT INTO Agents (Name,StoreID) VALUES ('Ben', 2);
INSERT INTO Agents (Name,StoreID) VALUES ('James', 2);
INSERT INTO Agents (Name,StoreID) VALUES ('Natsuo',3);
INSERT INTO Agents (Name,StoreID) VALUES ('Matheus',4);

INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (1,500);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (2,100);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (3,200);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (4,300);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (5,250);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (6,400);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (7,200);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (8,100);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (1,500);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (6,800);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (3,1500);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (2,50);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (7,789);
INSERT INTO Sales (AgentID,Value) VALUES (5,230);
```

For each `Store`, I'd like to get the average sum of sales, the agent that has gained the most and least - with one query.

I know how to get this information with separate queries, but I'd like to use a single query.

This is the output I'd like to have:

```
New York       | 660 | James   | 1200 | Mark    | 300
Paris          | 950 | Gaston  | 1700 | Didier  | 150
Rio de Janeiro | 100 | Matheus |  100 | Matheus | 100
Tokyo          | 989 | Natsuo  |  989 | Natsuo  | 989
```

This is what I have so far:

```
WITH AgentStats
AS (
    SELECT Stores.NAME StoreName,
    Agents.NAME AgentName,
    SUM(Value) TotalValue
    FROM Sales
    LEFT JOIN Agents ON Agents.ID = Sales.AgentID
    LEFT JOIN Stores ON Stores.ID = Agents.StoreID
    GROUP BY Stores.NAME,
    Sales.AgentID,
    Agents.NAME
    )
SELECT StoreName,
    AVG(TotalValue),
    MAX(TotalValue),
    MIN(TotalValue)
FROM AgentStats
GROUP BY StoreName
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want Sum of sales per store and Avg, max and min agent wise in single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
;With Totals as (
    select
        s.AgentID,
        StoreID,
        SUM(Value) as TotalSales
    from
        Agents a
            inner join
        Sales s
            on
                a.ID = s.AgentID
    group by s.AgentID,
    StoreID
), Ordered as (
    select
        AgentID,
        StoreID,
        TotalSales,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreID ORDER BY TotalSales) as rnLow,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreID ORDER BY TotalSales desc) as rnHigh,
        AVG(TotalSales) OVER (PARTITION BY StoreID) as StoreAverage
    from
        Totals
)
select
    st.Name,
    o1.StoreAverage,
    a1.Name,
    o1.TotalSales,
    a2.Name,
    o2.TotalSales
from
    Stores st
        inner join
    Ordered o1
        on
            st.ID = o1.StoreID and
            o1.rnHigh = 1
        inner join
    Agents a1
        on
            o1.AgentID = a1.ID
        inner join
    Ordered o2
        on
            st.ID = o2.StoreID and
            o2.rnLow = 1
        inner join
    Agents a2
        on
            o2.AgentID = a2.ID
```

Result:

```
Name                StoreAverage          Name      TotalSales   Name     TotalSales
------------------- --------------------- --------- ------------ -------- ---------------------
Paris               950.00                Gaston    1700.00      Didier   150.00
New York            660.00                James     1200.00      Mark     300.00
Tokyo               989.00                Natsuo    989.00       Natsuo   989.00
Rio de Janeiro      100.00                Matheus   100.00       Matheus  100.00
```

Which seems to match your requirement. Note that we split it into two separate CTEs where we first calculate the individual agent totals and then compute based on those results.

We work with `ROW_NUMBER()` since you're not just wanting to find, say, the `MIN` or `MAX` value for the sales - you're wanting to find the *row* in which the min or max value occurs. Also, because I've used `ROW_NUMBER()` you'll get arbitrary results if there's a tie for the top or bottom position - one of the rows will be row number 1 and the others will be ignored. If you need to deal with ties then we need more of a specification of what should be done when ties occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `Rank()` function to your cte and join it to itself:

```
WITH    AgentStats
          AS ( SELECT   Stores.NAME StoreName ,
                        Agents.NAME AgentName ,
                        SUM(Value) TotalValue ,
                        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Stores.name ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC ) AS highest ,
                        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Stores.name ORDER BY SUM(value) ) AS lowest
               FROM     Sales
                        LEFT JOIN Agents ON Agents.ID = Sales.AgentID
                        LEFT JOIN Stores ON Stores.ID = Agents.StoreID
               GROUP BY Stores.NAME ,
                        Sales.AgentID ,
                        Agents.NAME
             )
    SELECT  as1.StoreName ,
            AVG(as1.TotalValue) ,
            as2.AgentName ,
            MAX(as1.TotalValue) ,
            as3.AgentName ,
            MIN(as1.TotalValue)
    FROM    AgentStats as1
            INNER JOIN AgentStats as2 ON as1.StoreName = as2.StoreName
                                         AND as2.highest = 1
            INNER JOIN AgentStats as3 ON as1.StoreName = as3.StoreName
                                         AND as3.lowest = 1
    GROUP BY as1.StoreName ,
            as2.AgentName ,
            as3.AgentName
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to express agent that has gained the most, it is

1. Within the same store -> PARTITION BY StoreName
2. Who gained the most -> ORDER BY sum of sales
3. Name -> FIRST_VALUE(AgentName)

So final statement is

```
WITH StoreAgent AS
(
    SELECT dbo.Stores.Name AS StoreName, dbo.Agents.Name AS AgentName, SUM(Value) AS SumOfSales
    FROM dbo.Stores
    JOIN dbo.Agents ON dbo.Stores.ID = dbo.Agents.StoreID
    JOIN dbo.Sales ON dbo.Agents.ID = dbo.Sales.AgentID
    GROUP BY dbo.Stores.Name, dbo.Agents.Name
)
SELECT DISTINCT StoreName, AVG(SumOfSales) OVER (PARTITION BY StoreName),
    FIRST_VALUE(AgentName) OVER (PARTITION BY StoreName ORDER BY SumOfSales DESC) AS AgentMost,
    FIRST_VALUE(SumOfSales) OVER (PARTITION BY StoreName ORDER BY SumOfSales DESC) AS Most,
    FIRST_VALUE(AgentName) OVER (PARTITION BY StoreName ORDER BY SumOfSales) AS AgentLeast,
    FIRST_VALUE(SumOfSales) OVER (PARTITION BY StoreName ORDER BY SumOfSales) AS Least
FROM StoreAgent
```